# design question for transportation agency/workflow system

Tags: .net, workflow

I am designing a transportation agency/workflow system, and it including 3 types of people, customer who requests to transport some stuff, drivers who deliver the stuff, and truck manager who manages transport source/destination truck coordination and communicates/organizes drivers.

The system is expected to be a web site, and 3 kinds of people could use the web site to submit request, accept request, monitor status of specific stuff transportation, etc. The web site is more like an open agency or a workflow system.

I am wondering whether there are any existing technologies, tools or projects (better to be open source, but not a must) which I could build my application faster based on? I prefer to use .Net technologies, but not a must.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Technologies for what? Modeling workflows? Database access? Website construction?

Comment: Better has technologies or tools which could (1) either similar to my business scenario and use case or (2) based on what I can quickly build the web site. Any recommendations?

Comment: BTW: I know how to develop with workflow, database and web site construction, even if not a guru. :-)

I am asking scenario specific tools/projects/technologies. For example, if some people has already build some scenario similar to mine, I can reuse their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) (Windows Workflow Foundation) for modeling workflows.

For web technologies, there is either asp.net or asp.net MVC - see http://www.asp.net for more detail.

[Here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) is a library of free database schemas - possibly one of these can help you out.

Comment: Thanks! They general stuff for building a web based workflow system. Are there any project which is very similar to my requirements? For example, SharePoint has collaboration portal which could easily be used to build application for collaboration.

Comment: @George2 - Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try [bizagi](http://www.bizagi.com/), we were considering and i did a few prototypes with it. You may not even have to write code.